# How to Update Data Source in C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I am working on a Windows Form-Based application in Visual Studio 2008 using C# with an Access database as a back end. I added the Access database into the project by going to `Data->Add New Data Source` and I am able to retrieve data from the database's custom-made `DataSet` perfectly.

My next goal is to save new data back into the Access database, creating a new row. For the life of me, however, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. It looks like I need either an `OLEDbConnection` to the database or a `TableAdapter` hooked up to the database, but I don't seem to have either one of those. I'd think they would be premade or something when I added the new data source, just like the `DataSet` was, but if that's the case I can't figure out how to reference them.

What is the best way to add data back into a data source that's been added to the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a (configured) TableAdapter, it is in a sub-namespace with your (generated) Dataset.

Somewhere in your code there has to be an `Adapter.Fill(table)`, find it.
Copy it and change it to `Adapter.Update(table)` to write back to the database.

Instead of talking you through the multiple other ways of adding a record, have a look at the [videos here](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=4979)

Comment: Accepted because that link provided me with a much better understanding of the underlying system, so I could solve it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up solving it:
I had to create a new table adapter, create a new row, and then update the table adapter with it.

```
// Set up the table adapter and new row
MyDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeTableAdapter adapter;
adapter = new MyDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeeTableAdapter();
MyDataSet.EmployeeDataTable table = adapter.GetData();
MyDataSet.EmployeeRow newRow;
newRow = table.NewEmployeeRow();

// Insert the values of the fields into the new row here

// Save the row
table.AddEmployeeRow(newRow);
adapter.Update(table);
```

Thanks for the help!